# How not to import part of the code in ssr mode?

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, server-side-rendering

There are some imports in components like:

```
import someLib from '@/someFolder'
```

But it should not be in a separate file that is used to launch ssr.
I tried to make a substitution and created an intermediate file for export. The following type.

But they are still present in the final bundle, which is designed to be launched from node.
There are directives like window, the document of which should not be in node target mode.

How to remove a folder from the Vue collector, I tried to use code like:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
  config.plugin('copy').tap(options => {
    options[0][0].ignore.push('folderToExclude/**/*');
    return options;
  });
}
```

But this also throws the error Cannot call .tap() on a plugin that has not yet been defined.

How can I remove imported libraries in components from an assembly?